# Is there some rule for when one should pronounce 'te' as 'ta' in a song?

Tags: pronunciation, song

At [0:37 in the OP of the anime Gotoubun no Hanayome](https://youtu.be/tF04aIba5p8?t=33), Miku pronounces her lyrics 'kizuite' as 'kizuita'. I wonder if there's some singing rule for when this should be done.

Comment: Sounds like kizuite to me.

Comment: Do you know how "te" and "ta" are pronounced?  "te" is pronounced like "tay" rhyming with "day".  "ta" is pronounced like "taw" rhyming with "paw".  The singer very clearly pronounces *kizuite* correctly.

Comment: @Angelos I'd considered that.  I'd also considered that in English we slur our vowels a lot to the point that they sometimes all nearly sound the same.  It's an approximation nothing more.  Though I didn't say at all that "te" is pronounced like "taw".  I said "ta" is pronounced like "taw".  Anyhow.

Comment: It's indeed a bit more open than /e/. There are no rules. It's just the way she sings.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with aguijonazo. I don't have expertise in phonetics, but now that you mention it, it does sound like something in between て and た to my ears (as a native speaker). However, there is no rule that says one should pronounce it this way in a song. It just happened to sound like that as she was trying to sing it in a cute way.